# NSFW - Trying to create a Latin motto for a coat of arms - Edited for clarity

Tags: grammar-choice, declension, word-order

So, I took a couple years of Latin in school, but it's been awhile. I was trying to create this motto, and I'm not sure if I'm declining the nouns properly. Also not sure I remember if word order is important.

This motto is pretty NSFW, so, you have been warned.

> In Mentulīs Fēminārum Crīsāte

The intended translation in English is:

> Grind on the Dicks of Women. Or, roughly, Ride Girl Cock.

Comment: I hate to think what your coat of arms will depict. Do you really think it a suitable question for th[s forum?

Comment: A raven, a heart, a book, and a floppy disk. Suitable? Are the people who frequent this forum not up for answering the question? If you know of somewhere I can ask this question of more serious students of Latin, I'm all ears.

Comment: It's hard to say too much without knowing what it is that you're trying to express, but what you have is almost certainly incorrect. In the first place, the verb *crisare* is (at least in classical Latin) intransitive; so it can't take an accusative direct object, which is what *mentulas* appears to be. Also, *mentula* is (again, at least in classical Latin) the male sexual organ specifically; so *mentulas feminarum* seems suspect because, based on the forms, it's saying that the *feminae* are the possessors of the *mentulae*.

Comment: That second part is intentional. It is referring to the sexual organs of trans women, unfortunately, I couldn't find a cleaner way of expressing it. It sounds like I'm missing a preposition, and also if my hasty internet research is correct, that using in to mean on would require mentula to take the ablative, so mentulīs. It looks like the correct phrasing would be In Mentulīs Fēminārum Crīsāte?

Comment: If you want help with a translation, you should always explain in the question what it is that you are trying to achieve, instead of just giving your attempt without telling what it attempts to say. If you want to hide something from accidental view, start a paragraph with `>!`. // Users here certainly have the aptitude to help with your translation problem. Whether they want to help with this specific topic (or perhaps vote down or to close) is up to every user to decide.

Comment: Yes, that was the only way I could make sense of what you had done; but I didn't know whether it was your intended meaning and didn't want to assume. I agree with Joonas: you should just update your question to explain what exactly you're trying to express. Context matters.

Comment: This doesn't deserve the attention that it's getting. I vote we close it down.

Comment: @TomCotton It's an unconventional question, but it does certainly seem to be on-topic as defined in the Help Center (asking for help with a translation), and it's no more obscene than the worst of Catullus. If I remember right, Martial even has an epigram specifically about this topic.

Comment: A technical note to @TomCotton and others: To cast a vote to close, click the little gray button "close" under the question, choose an appropriate reason and hit "Vote To Close". (Alternatively, you can click "flag" and choose "Should be closed...".) Users like yourself can vote to close and reopen questions, and that his how most of the moderation is supposed to work. I prefer to leave questions like this for the community to decide, so I encourage everyone to vote. (Once there is a vote to close, others may vote to keep open [here](https://latin.stackexchange.com/review/close).)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your overall phrasing seems reasonable, though the words *ceveō* and *crīsō* are rare enough that I've never seen them used with any description of an object (even in the entirety of the Packhum corpus). The main questions are to do with vocabulary.

*Mentula* is a very standard obscene word for the male genitalia. Alternatives include *verpus* (specifically when erect) and *pēnis* (slang, but common enough that Cicero notes it couldn't be used for its original meaning any more). Alternatively, Martial has a satirical epigram about a woman penetrating another woman (I.90). He uses the word *landīca* "clitoris", though this word was never found in any of the other poets, and seems to have been incredibly obscene. (It's not that it's just rare, because it's also found in various graffiti, and Cicero (Ad Familiares 9.22) comments on a scandal when someone said it in the Senate by accident.)

*Fēmina* is a somewhat scientific word for "woman", used in biology and grammar. Alternatives include *uxor* (literally "wife") and *mulier* (the most common out of the three). But rather than using the genitive for this, I would go with an adjective: *muliebris* "of a woman, feminine" or *fēminīnus* (less common and more technical).

*Crīsō* is a rather rare word, but is definitely attested. *Crīsō* means to take an active role while being penetrated vaginally; *ceveō* means the same thing anally. Or maybe *crīsō* was always used for women and *ceveō* with men: the words aren't common enough to be sure (since e.g. there's no instance of either being unambiguously used for anal sex with a woman). Both are typically translated as "ride" in English.

Comment: Since adjectives have to match the case and number of the nouns they describe, if I wanted to keep mentula, would In Mentulīs Muliebribus Crīsāte be correct?

Comment: @Jessica Yep, looks right to me